# In 64 bit floating point why does sqrt(2^52+1)-sqrt(2^52) equal 0

Tags: math, floating-point

Why is it that when I put this equation in matlab it equals 0 but when I do (2^52+1) -2^52 it gives me 1, aren't they the same equation. I think I kind of understand how 64bit float can't represent odd numbers past 2^53-1 but these numbers are not even close to that

Comment: Using python's decimal module you can see that `sqrt(2^52 +1)` has a decimal expansion that begins `67108864.00000000745`. There isn't enough precision in a 52-bit mantissa to hold that. The decimal part is lopped off entirely.

Comment: so does that mean the computer is able to hold the value 2^52+1 exactly but isnt able to hold sqrt(2^52+1) exactly?

Answer (score 2):

There are `2^52` double precision numbers between `2^52` and `2^53-1` which the `sqrt` function maps to (approximately) the interval `[2^26, sqrt(2)*2^26]`. The latter contains just `2^52/sqrt(2)` numbers, which means a lot of numbers `x` must map to the same `sqrt(x)`.